# Gradient of a convex function is continuous on the interior of its domain

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a convex, lower semicontinuous, and proper function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable on its domain, is it true that its gradient $\nabla f$ is continuous on the interior of the domain of $f$? Here I am taking $\text{dom}f = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x)<\infty\}$. What I came up with was that for such a function $f$, it must be true that $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous on its domain and then by Rademacher's theorem it is locally differentiable a.e.. This doesn't get what I want, however. Anyone have a proof or counter example?

Edit: this is corollary 9.20 in Rockafellar and Wets, as it turns out.

Comment: Locally Lipschitz doesn't help.  Consider $f(x) = |x|$ on $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: I can prove it for $n = 1$ using the fact that $\nabla f = f'$ is increasing, and the mean value theorem.  But this doesn't help for $n > 1$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith that's not differentiable to begin with, not applicable.

Comment: I wasn't presenting it as a counterexample.  I was presenting it as an example that your argument was the wrong direction to go.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591521/convex-functions-gradient although no-one answered it there.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith If you see in my edit, it's a corollary from Rockafellar and Wets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, it is sufficient to prove $\nabla f$ is continuous at $x = 0$ when $\nabla f(0) = 0$.  Suppose $x_n \to 0$ is such that $|\nabla f(x_n)| > a > 0$.  Given $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(0,2\epsilon) \subset \text{dom}(f)$, pick $n$ so that $x_n \in B(0,\epsilon)$ and $f(x_n) - f(0) > -\epsilon^2$.  We know there exists $y \in B(x_n,\epsilon)$, $y \ne x_n$, such that
$$ f(y) \ge f(x_n) + a |x_n - y| $$
(that is, choose $y$ in the direction of $\nabla f(x_n)$ close to $x_n$).
For $t \in \mathbb R$, let $z_t = t(y-x_n) + x_n$.  By convexity, see that for $t \ge 1$
$$ \tfrac1t f(z_t) + (1-\tfrac{1}t) f(z_0) \ge f(z_1) ,$$
that is
$$ f(z_t) \ge f(x_n) + a t |x_n-y| .$$
Choose $t = \epsilon / |x_n - y|$.  Note that $|z_t| < 2 \epsilon$.
Then
$$ f(z_t) - f(0) = f(z_t) - f(x_n) + f(x_n) - f(0) \ge a \epsilon - \epsilon^2 . $$
This contradicts that $\nabla f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating this post with the follow-up question: If $f$ is a convex function defined on some convex set $E\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and if it is differentiable on $E$, is it true that its gradient must be continuous on $E$ (and not only in the interior) ?

Comment: I believe this is very much related, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524930/example-of-function-being-two-times-differentiable-at-a-point-but-not-c2

Comment: @TSF: thank you, but I believe that the convexity assumption is essential. Indeed, if a convex function is differentiable on $E$, then it is automatically $C^1$ in the interior of $E$, and I am trying to determine whether it is actually $C^1$ on the whole $E$.

Comment: What about the function $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ with $E=[-1,1]$? Then the gradient doesn't exist at $1$ or $-1$. I guess it depends on what you mean by differentiable on $E$, since if $E$ is a closed set you have to deal with the boundary anyways?

Comment: Regarding how to define the differentiability on the boundary, you can say the following. Wlog, assume that $E$ has nonempty interior. Then, $f$ is differentiable at $x\in E$ iff there is a vector $u\in\mathbb R^d$ such that for all $h\in T_xE$, $f(x+h)=f(x)+u^\top h+o(h)$, where $T_xE$ is the convex cone of all $h\in\mathbb R^d$ such that $x+th\in E$ for small enough $t>0$. Since $E$ has nonempty interior, you can show that $u$ is unique (otherwise, $u$ is unique if you impose that it belongs to the linear span of $E-x$).

Comment: Then, I believe that the following is true (but it needs to be proved): If $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is a convex function on a convex set $E\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ that is differentiable at every point of $E$, then, there exists a convex set $\tilde E\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ and a convex function $\tilde f:\tilde E\to\mathbb R$ such that:
(i) $f$ is the restriction of $\tilde f$ to $E$;
(ii) $\tilde f$ is differentiable on $\tilde E$;
(iii) $\tilde E$ is a neighborhood of every point of $E$.

Comment: Perhaps even more generally, I believe that it is true that if $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is a convex function defined on a convex set $E\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ and if, at every point $x\in E$, $f$ has at least one subgradient, then $f$ can be extended to a convex function on some convex set $\tilde E$ that is a neighborhood of every point of $E$.